# Media queries, Bootstrap ou os dois?

Tags: bootstrap, media-queries

Sou novo no ramo, apesar de estar no 3°semestre da faculdade, comecei a estudar desenvolvimento web a uns 15 dias, A minha dúvida é se eu devo usar apenas o bootstrap ou uso além dele, as media queries também? O bootstrap adiciona comandos e funcionalidades ao html5, é isso?

Comment: Bootstrap é para facilitar as coisas, aprenda usar os grids dele e já conseguirá fazer muitas coisas, mas ainda sim terá muitas coisas personalizadas que você terá que fazer manualmente, ou seja bootstrap é html e css, html5 é apenas um conjunto de funcionalidades, o bootstrap adiciona funcionalidades, mas não ao html5, o bootstrap faz uso do js, css3 e html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rafael, se está iniciando agora, sugiro que comece a estudar as ferramentas básicas para desenvolvimento web, que são **1: HTML**, **2: CSS** e **3: Javascript**. Um bom começo seria os cursos da [Universidade XTI](https://www.youtube.com/user/java8cia/playlists). Faz os cursos nessa ordem.

Quanto ao Bootstrap, trata-se de um Framework que possui alguns *estilos CSS pré-definidos* que você pode utilizar pra agilizar o trabalho.

Sucesso, bons estudos cara.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Vou dar uma olhada nos cursos da XTI. Estou terminando o da udacity de introdução ao Html5, CSS3 e Bootstrap. Valeu!